# Batch file in MAC

Tags: macos, batch-file

I've developed a Javscript application. It can be played online but I want to give users the possibility to play it offline.
So I've developed a batch file on Windows that searches for the google chrome executable and calls it with some flags that allows the application to read local files, etc...
This is the bat:

```
@echo off
echo STARTING APPLICATION
if "%CHROMEPATH%"==""  for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%a in (`reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ /s /f \chrome.exe ^| findstr Application`) do set CHROMEPATH=%%c %%d %%e

if "%CHROMEPATH%"=="" (
    echo CANNOT CONTINUE: GOOGLE CHROME MUST BE INSTALLED IN ORDER TO PLAY THE OFFLINE VERSION. PLEASE DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL IT AND THEN RE-RUN THIS FILE.
    set /p DUMMY=Hit ENTER to continue...
    ) else (
    "%CHROMEPATH%" %cd%/index.html --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security  --enable-file-cookies --user-data-dir=c:\chromeLocalWebeaser
    )
```

Can anybody help me to understand how to do the same thing on MAC computers?
thanks

Comment: You can't run batch scripts on Macs; a batch script is a list of commands designed for the Windows command prompt. You're going to need to convert the script to **bash**, which is a totally separate language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should have been asked on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I do know batch files are only for windows. I was asking how to achieve the same result on mac...